# SWT Use Composite from File

Tags: java, swt, ctabitem

I am trying to use a composite that I have created in a separate file in my app.
I am unsure how to set the control of my tab to the compsoite file.

Package: hm_forms
Composite File: Comp_HM.java
Main File: Frm_Main.java
Control: tabHM

I am thinking its got to be close to.

```
Composite Comp_HM = hm_Forms.Comp_HM;
tabHM.setControl(Comp_HM);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Composite Comp_HM = hm_Forms.Comp_HM;
tabHM.setControl(new Comp_HM());
```

You have to create an instance of your custom composite and pass it into the `setControl` method.

Comment: In order to make it work I ended up using.
tabHM.setControl(new hm_Forms.Comp_HM(tabFolder_main, SWT.NONE));
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.